# Ubuntu 13.04 not booting from hard drive after installing from USB

Tags: installation, boot, usb, hard-drive

I installed 13.04 from a USB on my desktop and everything is fine until I shut down, go to suspend or restart.  It asks for a boot-able drive.  I checked the BIOS and the hard drive is the first boot-able option.  When I put the USB in and restart it loads everything over again and everything is running very slow on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Boot from your Ubuntu USB drive.

Then follow these instructions:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair